# React JSON.stringfy get only the values

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

appNum is set as an [Object object] which looks like this in the database 'appNum' : **value**

```
const StringAppNum = JSON.stringify(appNum);
console.log (StringAppNum);
```

The result is {"appNum":"#APT924"}

I only want to get **#APT924**
Is there a way to do that?

Comment: have you tried console.log (StringAppNum.appNum)?

Comment: it reads **undefined**

Answer (score 0):

Try the Following solution:

```js
const StringAppNum = JSON.stringify(appNum);
const ParsedAppNum = JSON.parse(StringAppNum)
console.log (ParsedAppNum.appNum);
```